# What is the shortest path to updating a React app on GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github

I'm trying to update my code and that the updates show on Github pages. The process that I'm following now is:

1. Change the code on my editor from "Hello" to "This is my react app today" . E.g.:

```html
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1> This is my react app today </h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

2. git add .
3. git commit -m "New Commit"
4. git push
5. npm run deploy

Then I can see the commit change in Github.com and after some time the changes load on the Github Pages -> https://miguelinera.github.io/my-app/

Is there a shorter path that I should be following?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it takes time for your app changes to take effect on GitHub Pages is because the server has to build and deploy your code. There are many processes involved and checks that has to pass. You can view the progress in the Actions tab of your repository on GitHub after push.

There are some tools that make the git flow simpler, but not faster.

Have a look at [GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) and the [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) package

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Github workflow for `master` branch, so you don't have to do the `npm run deploy`. That's what I do anyways.

Comment: Thanks Khayliang! Another question. Very strangely my commits don't get published on the Gitbhub Pages until I change the source of the branch from "main" to "gh-pages" and then back to "main". Does this make any sense?

Comment: wdym change the source, do u mean change source in ur github repository settings? I checked out ur repo and everything looks alright. 

I'm just throwing some idea out: It might be that after github deploys ur build, your browser doesn't fetch the new build and instead uses the old cached version.

After building if ur page doesn't change, try clearing your browser history and cache.